# How to set up a route configuration so that a parent and child route is redirected to after loading the app?

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

Ive looked on the udemy tutorial as well as in the angular2 docs for how to do a redirect. It seems like this is correct, but it's not working, and there are no error messages. I want my app after loading to go to the /whatsup/today component. I have sucessfully done a redirect that goes directly to a component that has no child, but when there is a child involved in the redirect does not work, and there is no error.

app.routes.ts

```
 export const routes: RouterConfig = [
      {path: '', redirectTo:"/whatsup/today", pathMatch:"full"},
      { path: 'whatsup', component: Whatsup,
        children:[
          {path:"today", component:Calendar,
          children:[
            {path:'info/:mod-title/:mod-desc/:mod-pic', component:ModalInfo},
            {path:'map/:lat/:lng', component:Map}
          ]
          }
        ]
      },
    ...
```

Comment: `/whatsup/today` doesn't lead anywhere. You would need a "default route" for the children of `today` of redirect to `/whatsup/today/info/title/desc/pic` or `/whatsup/today/map/123/456`

Comment: Thanks, you were right, that did the trick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`/whatsup/today` doesn't lead anywhere. You would need a "default route" for the children of `today` redirect to `/whatsup/today/info/title/desc/pic` or `/whatsup/today/map/123/456`